# Multiple recomposition when ViewModel with Room passed to composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I have almost empty view model that works with Room db. I creating an instance of the view model and pass it to my @Composable screen. But it leads to multiple recompositions. All the code below. Could someone explain why this happening?

UI (is drawn 5 times):

```
@Composable
fun AddCollectionScreen(vm: AddCollectionHiltViewModel) = Screen(
    title = "Create Collection"
) {
    Log.d("TAG322", "Recomposition. AddCollectionScreen")
    vm
}
```

UI (is drawn 1 time):

```
@Composable
fun AddCollectionScreen() = Screen(
    title = "Create Collection"
) {
    val vm: AddCollectionHiltViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    Log.d("TAG322", "Recomposition. AddCollectionScreen")
    vm
}
```

View model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddCollectionHiltViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    val collection = Collection("") // Room entity. No extra recompositions without this line
}

abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    /*
    * If the user leaves the screen before getList(...) returns a value,
    *  the system calls onCleared and the ViewModel’s CoroutineScope will be canceled.
    *  This will make sure that the gamesLiveData.value will not be modified,
    * and the code will not attempt to update a no longer existing screen.*/
    override fun onCleared() {
        viewModelScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Nav Graph:|

```
@Composable
fun AppNavGraph() {
    Log.d("TAG322", "Recomposition. AppNavGraph")
    NavHost(
        navController = findNavigationState().navHostController,
        startDestination = HomeTab.Graph.route
    ) {
        homeNavGraph()
        toolsNavGraph()
        settingsNavGraph()
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.homeNavGraph() {
    Log.d("TAG322", "Recomposition. homeNavGraph")
    navigation(
        route = HomeTab.Graph.route,
        startDestination = HomeTab.Collections.route,
    ) {
        composable(HomeTab.Collections.route) {
            CollectionsScreen()
        }
        composable(
            route = HomeTab.AddCollection.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(HomeTab.AddCollection.ARG_REASON) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(HomeTab.AddCollection.ARG_COLLECTION_ID) {
                    type = NavType.IdType
                }
            )
        ) {
            Log.d("TAG322", "Recomposition. AddCollection composable")
//            val reason = it.arguments?.getString(HomeTab.AddCollection.ARG_REASON)
//                ?.let(ScreenMode::fromValue) ?: throw RuntimeException("Wrong reason argument!")
//            val collectionId = it.arguments?.getId(HomeTab.AddCollection.ARG_COLLECTION_ID)
//                ?: throw RuntimeException("Wrong collectionId argument!")
//            val vm = addCollectionViewModel(reason, collectionId)
            val vm: AddCollectionHiltViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            AddCollectionScreen(vm)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem disappears if I either move move ViewModel creation to `AddCollectionScreen()` or remove creating db entity from the ViewModel. However I want to pass it as a parameter, because I have wrapper for each screen to manage toolbar and bottom bar from single place:
(the issue does reproducible when the commented lines below are commented)

```
@Composable
fun Screen(
    title: String? = null,
    topBarActions: (@Composable RowScope.() -> Unit)? = null,
    bottomBar: BottomBarState = BottomBarState.BottomNavigation,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
//    val appBarState = findAppBarState()
//    val bottomBarState = findBottomBarState()
//
//    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
//        appBarState.value = title?.let { AppBarState(it, topBarActions) }
//        bottomBarState.value = bottomBar
//    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

dependencies {
implementation(project("::core"))

```
implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.9.10-1.0.13")

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.09.00"))
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

// Compose
val verCompose = "1.5.4"
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$verCompose")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:$verCompose")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$verCompose")
implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$verCompose")
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.4")
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.32.0")

// Hilt
val verHilt = "2.48.1"
ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$verHilt")
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$verHilt")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-beta01")

// Room components
val roomVersion = "2.6.0"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$roomVersion")
```

}

Logs:

```
2023-10-28 20:31:46.345 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. MainScreen
2023-10-28 20:31:46.348 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. AppNavGraph
2023-10-28 20:31:46.349 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. homeNavGraph
2023-10-28 20:31:46.502 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. CollectionsScreen
2023-10-28 20:31:48.156 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. AddCollection composable
2023-10-28 20:31:48.511 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. AddCollection composable
2023-10-28 20:31:48.156 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. AddCollection composable
2023-10-28 20:31:48.511 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. AddCollection composable
----------------------------- Back button clicked -----------------------------------
2023-10-28 20:32:00.312 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. AddCollection composable
2023-10-28 20:32:00.315 21327-21327 TAG322    D  Recomposition. CollectionsScreen
```

Interesting fact that if I remove `implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.4")` dependency (animated screen show/fade), there will be 2 less recompositions (2+1 instead of 4+1)

Comment: I have also faced the same issue in the latest navigation. It is recomposes 4 times because it uses animation. so I preferred to stay with 2.6.2 which is working fine for me. I have raised the issue with Google but they have said it is intended behaviour.

Comment: @ChiragThummar Thanks, could you please share a link to your question?

Comment: link to google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/302212882